# How do you map a cardinality operation to a set of sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set $X$ which contains {0,1},{0,1,2,3},{0,1,2}

I know that a cardinality operation returns the number of members in a set, but how would I return the number of members within the subsets - If I do #$X$ I am returned 3 in this example, so is there a method of iteratively calculating cardinality and adding it to a set?

Expected Output: {2,4,3}

Comment: $\{\#A\mid A\in X\}$.

Comment: I completely forgot about set composition rules! Thank you. If you write it as an answer I’ll mark it as correct.